# Fantasy premier league dream team algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

For those of you who are not familiar with FPL, here's a short version. You have players playing as either Goalkeeper, Defender, Midfielder or Forward. Each player has some price (either rounded to .5 or .0), and based on their real life performance you earn points. You have a budget of 100£ and you need to build a team, keeping in mind you have a limit for players on each position.

**Now, the problem is: If you have all players prices, their positions and total number of points they scored in a season, how do you find the highest scoring team with, for example, 4-4-2 formation? (1GK, 4DEF, 4MID, 2FWD)**

I guess this is a variation of knapsack problem, where you have limitations to have exactly 11 players, and exactly 4-4-2 formation.
So is that the best way to solve this problem and how would you solve it with these modifications/limitations, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Formulate the problem as an integer program and solve it using your favorite IP solver (e.g., https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/).

For each player `p`, the formulation has a 0-1 decision variable `x_p` that is 1 if the player is on the team.

```
maximize sum_{p in players} points-scored(p)
subject to
sum_{p in players} price(p) x_p <= 100
sum_{p in goalkeepers} x_p <= 1
sum_{p in defenders} x_p <= 4
sum_{p in midfielders} x_p <= 4
sum_{p in forwards} x_p <= 2
for all p in players, x_p in {0, 1}
```